# RMST code for calculating rmst for one catagorical variable

Tags: r

give the r code for calculating RMST for one categorical variable in cox regression model

actually, RMST is the area under Kaplan-Meier curve, A benefit of the use of RMST is that it does not make this assumption. Studies indicate that RMST is comparable to PH in detecting differences between arms when hazards are proportional, but better when hazards are not proportional. Here i want to calculate RMST value for atleast one categorical variable which has 2 categories. How can we calculate it in r for one categorical variable.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use an existing package like `RISCA::rmst` or `survRM2::rmst2`?

Either way, the restricted mean survival time is simply the area under a Kaplan-Meier curve up to some cut-off time `tau` -- hence the *restricted*. This is quite simple to calculate via the trapezoidal rule:

```r
## Calculate RMST for one group
rmst <- function(time, status, tau) {
   f <- survival::survfit(survival::Surv(time, status) ~ 1)
   i <- f$time <= tau
   
   time_delta <- diff(c(0, sort(f$time[i]), tau))
   auc <- time_delta * c(1, f$surv[i])
   sum(auc)
}

data("cancer", package="survival")
tapply(veteran, veteran$trt, \(x) rmst(x$time, x$status, tau=140))

#>     1     2 
#> 84.79 71.90
```

Compare this against a pre-packaged solution (which uses a very similar approach):

```r
## Expects a 0/1 dummy for group
survRM2::rmst2(veteran$time, veteran$status, veteran$trt-1, tau=140)

#> The truncation time: tau = 140  was specified. 
#> 
#> Restricted Mean Survival Time (RMST) by arm 
#>                Est. 
#> RMST (arm=1) 71.901 
#> RMST (arm=0) 84.786
```

It's usually the *difference* in RMST between groups which is of interest, you can get a point estimate for that by simply subtracting the two values to be compared. Estimators for variance are quite a bit more involved.